# Need to group_by all the table fields in PostgreSQL 8.4 but not in 9.1?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have this query which runs fine in PostgreSQL 9.1:

```
    tbl_grupos = dbs.query(Grupos).\
                      join(Cursos).\
                      join(AlumnosEnGrupos).\
                      join(Alumnos).\
                      outerjoin(join_clientes).\
                      filter(and_(cond_cliente,
                                  cond_curso,
                                  cond_grupo,
                                  cond_grupos,
                                  cond_profesor,
                                  Grupos.fecha_inicio <= self.fecha_fin,
                                  Grupos.fecha_fin >= self.fecha_inicio,
                                  Grupos.confirmado == True,
                                  )).\
                      order_by(Grupos.nombre, Grupos.id_).\
                      group_by(Grupos.nombre, Grupos.id_).\
                      having(func.count(AlumnosEnGrupos.id_) > 0)
```

The problem comes when I run it in a remote server with PostgreSQL 8.4 installed. It gives me the following error message:

```
Error - <class 'sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError'>: (ProgrammingError) column "grupos.resumen_horario" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: ...grupos_fecha_fin, grupos.codigo AS grupos_codigo, grupos.res...
                                                             ^
 'SELECT grupos.id AS grupos_id, grupos.nombre AS grupos_nombre, grupos.fecha_inicio AS grupos_fecha_inicio, grupos.fecha_fin AS grupos_fecha_fin, grupos.codigo AS grupos_codigo, grupos.resumen_horario AS grupos_resumen_horario, grupos.profesores_grupo AS grupos_profesores_grupo, grupos.aulas AS grupos_aulas, grupos.limite_de_entrega_naco AS grupos_limite_de_entrega_naco, grupos.objetivos AS grupos_objetivos, grupos.capacidad AS grupos_capacidad, grupos.cancelaciones_al_mes AS grupos_cancelaciones_al_mes, grupos.horas_de_clase AS grupos_horas_de_clase, grupos.direccion AS grupos_direccion, grupos.estacion AS grupos_estacion, grupos.recibe_avisos AS grupos_recibe_avisos, grupos.recibe_avisos_alumno AS grupos_recibe_avisos_alumno, grupos.cod_objeto AS grupos_cod_objeto, grupos.lugar AS grupos_lugar, grupos.confirmado AS grupos_confirmado, grupos.id_curso AS grupos_id_curso, grupos.id_departamento AS grupos_id_departamento, grupos.id_centro AS grupos_id_centro, grupos.id_aula AS grupos_id_aula, grupos.id_profesor AS grupos_id_profesor, grupos.id_nivel AS grupos_id_nivel \nFROM grupos JOIN cursos ON cursos.id = grupos.id_curso JOIN alumnos_en_grupos ON grupos.id = alumnos_en_grupos.id_grupo JOIN alumnos ON alumnos.id = alumnos_en_grupos.id_alumno LEFT OUTER JOIN clientes ON clientes.id = cursos.id_cliente \nWHERE cursos.id_cliente = %(id_cliente_1)s AND grupos.fecha_inicio <= %(fecha_inicio_1)s AND grupos.fecha_fin >= %(fecha_fin_1)s AND grupos.confirmado = true GROUP BY grupos.nombre, grupos.fecha_inicio, grupos.fecha_fin, grupos.codigo, grupos.id \nHAVING count(alumnos_en_grupos.id) > %(count_1)s ORDER BY grupos.nombre, grupos.fecha_inicio, grupos.fecha_fin, grupos.codigo, grupos.id' {'id_cliente_1': 241, 'fecha_inicio_1': datetime.date(2014, 10, 24), 'fecha_fin_1': datetime.date(2014, 10, 1), 'count_1': 0}
```

It is basically saying that I need to `group_by` the column `grupos.resumen_horario`. So that is what I do, and then the query failed again saying that I had to add the next column to the `group_by`clause.

I kept adding columns from the table `Grupos` to the `group_by` clause as indicated by the error messages until I realised it is a bit absurd, especially considering that the table `Grupos` has around 20 columns.

I would like to understand what is happening and how could I solve this issue and make the query run in PostgreSQL 8.4 without having to add to the `group_by` clause all of the 30 columns of the table `Grupos`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It used to be that Postgresql required grouping by all the non-aggregating columns. Starting with (I think) version 9.1 it is now possible to group by the primary key columns (if they are part of the query of course). There is a write up [here](http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/08/postgresql-recognizing-functional.html) that may help explain.

**Update:** Depesz bloged about it [here](http://www.depesz.com/index.php/2010/08/08/waiting-for-9-1-recognize-functional-dependency-on-primary-keys/) as part of his "Waiting for 9.1" series of posts.

Comment: Thank you for the links Gsiems. So, in order for my query to work in PostgreSQL 8.4, do I really have to add the 30 columns that compose the table to the `group_by` clause? That will look just plain right horrible in the code, but I will have to try it anyway.